# Sorry, we couldn't find Test.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Tags: c#, macros, clickonce, xlsm

I am running a macro code from my C# application. I have placed the Test.xlsm file in the project itself with Properties:

Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: copy always.

However, I get the below exception, when I run the code.

> Sorry, we couldn't find Test.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I cannot give a hard-coded path since I have to create a clickOnce deployment of this project.

```
                // Define your Excel Objects 
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

           //Start Excel and open the workbook.
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Test.xlsm");

            // Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("Create", pFilePath1, pPath2);

            // Clean-up: Close the workbook
            xlWorkBook.Close(false);

            // Quit the Excel Application
            xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Is Test.xlsm in a project sub-folder by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. I added Application.StartupPath before the file name:

```
string workbookPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Test.xlsm";
//~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
```